# Using new[] in select query gives exception for .NET 8

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I could not find anything about this and therefore decided to post.

This code worked with `.NET 7` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Version 7.0.13`:

`Updated = p.ThreatAndCountermeasures.Count() > 0 ? new[] { p.Updated, p.ThreatAndCountermeasures.Max(tac => tac.Updated) }.Max() : p.Updated,`

With `.NET 8` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Version 8.0.0` I get the following exception:

> Query root of type 'InlineQueryRootExpression' wasn't handled by provider code. This issue happens when using a provider specific method on a different provider where it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

`new List<>` instead of `new[]` and it will work:

`Updated = p.ThreatAndCountermeasures.Count() > 0 ? new List<DateTime> { p.Updated, p.ThreatAndCountermeasures.Max(tac => tac.Updated) }.Max() : p.Updated,`

Issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32331

Comment: It's still unclear if there's an EF issue or a code issue. The query is certainly unusual. EF converts LINQ queries to SQL, so what SQL is this supposed to generate? In SQL you wouldn't check the `COUNT` before calculating a MAX either. In SQL Server 2022 you'd use something like `GREATEST(p.Updated,MAX(other.Updated))`. In earlier versions you'd have to use `IIF(MAX(other.Updated) is NULL OR p.Updated>MAX(other.Updated),p.Updated,MAX(other.Updated))`